# incremental backup of folder in linux whilst retaining attributes/ownership

Tags: linux, backup, directory

I'm trying to backup a folder (e.g) /web/sites to /backups/websites and retain  attributes, etc.

cp -Rp retains the information, yet isn't incremental

rsync -va seems to be great for incremental yet doesnt retain the attr/owner

Is it possible to tar, and pipe it through and untar whilst retaining attr/owner, if so, how can I do this? or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cp -pur seems to do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Going further than just an incremental copy, there's glastree ([website](http://old.igmus.org/code/)/[github](http://github.com/jeremywohl/glastree)): "the poor mans daily snapshot".